# VueJS - can't dynamicaly generate attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a component that has a button to open modal in the same element. I need to set attribute `v-b-modal-modal-[[this.data.id]]` to this modal:

```js
Vue.component('vue-tables-2-product', {
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    props: ['data', 'index', 'column'],
    template: `<div>
            <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
                <p class="my-4">[[ this.data.name ]]</p>
            </b-modal>
            <button @click="onClick(data.id)" :v-b-modal-modal-[[this.data.id]]="this.data.id">Detail</button></div>`,
});
```

but `Vue` raises an error:

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'v-b-modal-modal-[[this.data.id]]' is not a valid attribute name."

vue.js:1897 DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'v-b-modal-modal-[[this.data.id]]' is not a valid attribute name.
        at baseSetAttr (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:6772:10)
        at setAttr (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:6747:7)
        at Array.updateAttrs (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:6702:9)
        at invokeCreateHooks (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:6058:24)
        at createElm (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:5945:13)
        at createChildren (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:6042:11)
        at createElm (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:5943:11)
        at createChildren (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:6042:11)
        at createElm (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:5943:11)
        at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js:6464:9)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Move it to an option and call `v-bind` on it. When calling `v-bind` with no exclusive parameter, all parameters of the object are applied to the element:

```
<button @click="onClick(data.id)"  v-bind="params"> Details </button>

computed: {
  params() {
    return {
      [`-v-modal-modal-[[${this.data.id}]]`]: true
    }
  }
}
```